# Forest package: Tree connector apear reversed

Tags: forest, trees

For the following MWE, I am sing the {forest} package to make a hierarchy, however the node connector for the second level apears on the opposite side, it emerges from the opposite node on far LHs while it should be on the RHS. I do not know what is the issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}  

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 



\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



\begin{document}
\newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm}
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{forest}baseline, for tree={draw,edge=->},forked edges%For tree=draw, is to make the recrangles inclding the words, edge is to change all connectors to arrows
[
اللغة السامية
    [
    سامية شرقية     
        [الآكادية]       
    ]
    [
سامية غربية     
    ]   
[سامية جنوبية]   
]   
\end{forest}
\caption
[اللغة السامية]
{
اللغة السامية
\cite{bbbb}
}
\label{fig:اللغة السامية}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is the use of arabic language as the main language, and thus write from right to left, upon locally switching to a left to right language, the issue is resolved

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}  

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 



\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



\begin{document}
\newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm}
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{otherlanguage}{coptic}
\begin{forest}baseline, for tree={draw,edge=->},forked edges%For tree=draw, is to make the recrangles inclding the words, edge is to change all connectors to arrows
[
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{اللغة السامية}
    [
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{سامية شرقية}       
        [
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{الآكادية}      
        ]        
    ]
    [
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{سامية غربية}   
    ]   
[
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{سامية جنوبية}
]    
]   
\end{forest}
\end{otherlanguage}
\caption
[اللغة السامية]
{
اللغة السامية
\cite{bbbb}
}
\label{fig:اللغة السامية}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%

\end{document}
```

[image]